# Resolving snapshot versions of Grails plugins (deployed using the maven-publisher plugin)

Tags: grails, maven, ivy, grails-plugin, snapshot

Good day,

I'm trying to integrate our company's Grails plugins into our Maven repositories (our repositories are named 'snapshots' and 'releases').

To do that, I installed the maven-publisher plugin in all of our plugins, and I'm deploying them using the "grails maven-deploy" command. This works well.

However, if I deploy a SNAPSHOT version of a plugin (say, version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT), it gets properly deployed in our repository, but I can't install it in our applications (using version "latest.integration").

I'm using Grails 1.3.7.

First of all, when deployed, the actual artifact name has a timestamp added to it ("blablabla-1.0.0-20110421.122823-1.zip"). However, the version is still 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. I'm guessing that it's Maven that does that transformation.

However, Ivy doesn't seem to understand the transformation, or to handle SNAPSHOT versions. I get errors like:

```
==== http://myRepo/repository/snapshots: tried
-- artifact myOrg#blablabla;latest.integration!blablabla.zip:
http://myRepo/repository/snapshots/myOrg/blablabla/[revision]/blablabla-[revision].zip
```

Initial research has revealed that I could create a resolver pattern, but that seems a little bit complicated for something that should work out of the box, and my initial tests were not conclusive anyway (I tried a few patterns, none of which worked).

I should note that deploying my plugins locally using the "maven-install" command works, because the script create an artifact with the proper version (blablabla-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip) alongside the one with timestamps.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks!

Guillaume.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this modifying Artifactory snapshot repository configuration:

```
<snapshotVersionBehavior>non-unique</snapshotVersionBehavior>
```

Now when you have foo-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip and you upload it the name stays same.